# Haskell - Pass arbitrary function and argument list as arguments to another function

Tags: function, variables, haskell, arguments

My main goal is to redirect stderr to a file.

I got hold of the following code snippet...

```
catchOutput :: IO a -> IO (res, String)
catchOutput f = do
  tmpd <- getTemporaryDirectory
  (tmpf, tmph) <- openTempFile tmpd "haskell_stderr"
  stderr_dup <- hDuplicate stderr
  hDuplicateTo tmph stderr
  hClose tmph
  res <- f
  hDuplicateTo stderr_dup stderr
  str <- readFile tmpf
  removeFile tmpf
  return (res, str)
```

I hoped to make this more general and pass any function and argument list to catchOutput and get the function result as well as message written to stderr (if any).

I thought that an argument list of type [Data.Dynamic] might work but I failed to retrieve the function result with

```
res <- Data.List.foldl (f . fromDyn) Nothing $ args
```

Is this even possible?  Help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Passing a function and a list of arguments is needed in other languages, when e.g. they are strict or ridden with side-effects. In Haskell, there's no need to do that. If the function is pure, just pass its result (it's not evaluated anyway) as an `a`; otherwise pass a `IO a` action as you are doing above (it's not executed until later).

Comment: Why not pass the result of the function into `catchOutput` instead of trying to pass the function and its arguments?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is not reason to use `Data.Dynamic`. You already know type the return type of `f`, it's `a` so you can use just that, i.e.

```
catchOutput :: IO a -> IO (a, String)
```

Note though, that there some significant issues with your approach:

1. By redirecting `stderr` to a file, this will also affect all other concurrent threads. So you could possibly get unrelated data sent to the temporary file.
2. If an exception is thrown while `stderr` is redirected, the original `stderr` will not be restored. Any operation between the two `hDuplicateTo` lines (`hClose` and `f` in this case) could possibly throw an exception, or the thread may receive an asynchronous exception. For this reason, you have to use something like [bracket](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Control-Exception-Base.html#v:bracket) to make your code exception safe.

Comment: As I understand it one cannot generate a list where the elements have different types.  Thus the usage of Data.Dynamic for the different elements of the argument list.

Comment: Yes, you cannot have a list with elements of different types, but I don't see any lists in your code.